# Parsing specific data from body of json response

Tags: json, api, parsing

This is my code to request data from API

`

```
@app.route('/quote/{symbol}')
def quote(symbol):
    response = c.get_quote(symbol)


    return response.json()
```

`

This is my json response:

> 

```
{"SPY":{"assetType":"ETF","assetMainType":"EQUITY","cusip":"78462F103","assetSubType":"ETF","symbol":"SPY","description":"SPDR S&P 500","bidPrice":390.2,"bidSize":300,"bidId":"P","askPrice":390.21,"askSize":100,"askId":"P","lastPrice":389.02,"lastSize":2528800,"lastId":"P","openPrice":379.87,"highPrice":389.52,"lowPrice":379.68,"bidTick":" ","closePrice":389.02,"netChange":0.0,"totalVolume":100301958,"quoteTimeInLong":1667001600168,"tradeTimeInLong":1667001600004,"mark":389.02,"exchange":"p","exchangeName":"PACIFIC","marginable":true,"shortable":true,"volatility":0.0109,"digits":2,"52WkHigh":479.98,"52WkLow":348.11,"nAV":0.0,"peRatio":0.0,"divAmount":6.1757,"divYield":1.59,"divDate":"2022-09-16 00:00:00.000","securityStatus":"Normal","regularMarketLastPrice":389.02,"regularMarketLastSize":30,"regularMarketNetChange":0.0,"regularMarketTradeTimeInLong":1667001600004,"netPercentChangeInDouble":0.0,"markChangeInDouble":0.0,"markPercentChangeInDouble":0.0,"regularMarketPercentChangeInDouble":0.0,"delayed":false,"realtimeEntitled":true}}
```

> 

How do I get the response to only be a specific part of the body like "lastPrice"?

I'm a mewbie so I have searched for a solution but cant find anything that works yet.

Answer (score 1):

You do need to parse all of the JSON you get back, but you can access individual object properties once you've done that.

Assuming your data is in a variable named `data`...

```
console.log(data.SPY.lastPrice);
```

See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics

Answer (score 0):

Hello how are you? Basically you will take a variable that received a `response.json()` and put `res["SPY"]["lastPrice"]` or `res.SPY.lastPrice` it will give you the value **389.02**

Comment: An earlier post by @Brad already answered the question.